# Copy excel sheet data to another sheet using c#

Tags: c#, excel

In my excel sheet there are many cells filled with some information.
e.g sheet1

```
**Osdata**  
C:\Program Files (x86)  
Z:\Program Files\Google\Update  <br>
W:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\es-ES  <br>
C:\Program Files (x86)  <br>
q:\Program Files\Google\Update  <br>
W:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\es-ES  <br>
C:\Program Files (x86)  <br>
Z:\Program Files\Google\Update  <br>
P:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\es-ES  <br>
C:\Program Files (x86)  <br>
Z:\Program Files\Google\Update  <br>
X:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\es-ES  <br>
C:\Program Files (x86)  <br>
F:\Program Files\Google\Update  <br>
W:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\es-ES  <br>
**Files**   <br>
D:\MyFolder\Work    <br>
D:\PDF\Year\2016    <br>
E:\Games\Report\Tri <br>
E:\all\Reports\Like\12\P    <br>
D:\MyFolder\Work\32\WERT    <br>
D:\PDF\Year\2016\RET\12\ER  <br>
E:\Games\Report\Tri <br>
E:\all\Reports\Like <br>
D:\MyFolder\Work    <br>
D:\PDF\Year\2016    <br>
E:\Games\Report\Tri <br>
E:\all\Reports\Like <br>
D:\MyFolder\Work    <br>
D:\PDF\Year\2016    <br>
E:\Games\Report\Tri <br>
E:\all\Reports\Like <br>
**OthersData**  <br>
\\Games\AllGames\Data   <br>
\\Report\New\AllNew\Report  <br>
\\Re12\FERT\Like    <br>
```

now i want copy Osdata and Othersdata to sheet2.
these all are sample data.

Comment: Okay.  What have you tried and what specific problem are you having?

Comment: i didnt try anythying bcz i have no idea abt this. found some solution on net but those r copying cell with specific range only...

Answer (score 0):

Below links might be helpful to give you a start

[How to copy excel worksheets Into another excel workbook without opening the excel file in c# winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514966/how-to-copy-excel-worksheets-into-another-excel-workbook-without-opening-the-exc)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178800.aspx

Comment: Excel.Range from = workSheet.get_Range("A1","A100"); Excel.Range to = newWorksheet.get_Range("A1","A100"); from.Copy(to); 
this is coping the specific range , .i want to copy only Osdata and Othersdata

Answer (score 0):

Okay, 
First of all you need to read the current excel data.
**use this link** 
[Read Data From Excel file using CSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793442/how-to-read-data-from-excel-file-using-c-sharp)

Then, you will write the data you just read into another excel file.
**use this link**
[Export Data to excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746701/export-datatable-to-excel-file)

Hope this will help.

Comment: what do you mean by specific range?

Comment: Excel.Range from = workSheet.get_Range("A1","A100");
            Excel.Range to = newWorksheet.get_Range("A1","A100");

            from.Copy(to);   this is coping the specific range ,

Comment: See my above question..i want to copy only **Osdata** and **Othersdata**